# MvvmCross Dialog Fragment

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, dialogfragment

I'm developing a mobile app in Xamarin.Android using MvvmCross. In my app, I have added a button which should open a dialog fragment window when clicked. I went through the available tutorials but could not find proper solution. Has anyone tried implementing it ?

Comment: Please post some code you have tried till now

Comment: Dialog fragment is bind to viewmodel by using : 
              return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentTest,null);          
In axml of activity :  app:MvxBind="Click OpenDialogCommand;             In viewmodel of activity :                                                                     
   public IMvxCommand LoginCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand(() =>
                {    ShowViewModel<DialogFragmentViewModel>();  });
            }
        }

Comment: can you please edit your post and add that code? Also it would be nice to see how have you declarated your dialog fragment

Comment: I solved the problem using navigation service to navigate dialog fragment.

Comment: Would be nice to answer your question so others can know.